# If [crime] is OK, should we get rid of [police]?

Tags: discussion, tags

- [crime](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crime): 12 questions
- [police](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/police): 7 questions

Including 3 questions with both.

Can crime and police co-exist?

Comment: A small problem that I see is that not all [tag:police] questions are directly related to crime, such as "Police precinct jurisdiction data for joining UCR with census". I don't have a strong opinion on the topic, though.